# See PowerShell Verbose output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.17.2 with the PowerShell extension (1.4.3).  I have `Write-Verbose` statements in my code.  When I run the PowerShell script, the `Verbose` output doesn't seem to go anywhere.  How do I request that output be shown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest approach is to **execute**:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
```

**in the integrated PowerShell console** before invoking your script (and executing `$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` later to turn verbose output back off, if needed).

From that point on:

- running a script (starting it with (<kbd>F5</kbd>) or without (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) the debugger)
- highlighting a section of code and running the selection (<kbd>F8</kbd>)

will make `Write-Verbose` calls produce  output.

If you want to ***preset*** `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` every time the integrated console starts, put that statement in the **`$PROFILE` file**:

- If your *VS Code-specific* `$PROFILE` file already exists, simply run `psedit $PROFILE` from the integrated console.
- If not, create the file first *from the integrated console*: `New-Item -Type File $PROFILE`

Comment: Between the two, this answer "feels" more natural - I didn't really want to change the code (adding the extra "-Verbose") if I didn't have to.  This answer worked fine, so I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 1):

Verbose output by default it not shown, you need to declare `[CmdletBinding()]` in your function or script to enable the `-Verbose` parameter to be passed through in order have the option to display Verbose output.

You can 'cheat' though and pass `-Verbose` to `Write-Verbose "Hello Verbose" -Verbose` itself and that stream will appear in the console.

*(Tested with your two matching versions for VSCode and Extension on Mac (PS6 Beta 8) and can see the verbose output).*

```
function Test-Verbose {

    # This enables the function to have '-Verbose'.
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    Write-Output "Hello output!"

    # Will only be displayed if 'Test-Verbose' is passed '-Verbose'.
    Write-Verbose "Hello verbose"
}

Test-Verbose -Verbose
```